# Silverlight: Overriding Mouse Cursor

Tags: .net, silverlight

Is there a way to say that a mouse cursor set on one control overrides the mouse cursor on all clild controls?

Currently setting the cursor to the hourglass mostly works, but I've got one control that is keeping its original cursor.

Comment: Are you looking for a way other than setting default style templates for your controls?

Comment: My use case is showing and hiding a Wait cursor when the UI is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Strange that the children don't respect the cursor defined by the parent but thus is life. Worst case since this only effects one button you could try setting the cursor programmatically:

```
myButton.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

Answer (score 1):

Children will inherit the mouse cursor setting of their parents *unless* they have a mouse cursor setting of their own.

To avoid this, one solution involves placing a transparent control over the top whole area you want the busy cursor to be seen, and setting the cursor on that.

Comment: Ooo, I like that. Will it work even if the transparent control has hit test set to false?

Comment: @Jonathan, if you set `IsHitTestVisible` to false for the overlay, then the `Cursor` property is ignored.  So if you are happy to block user input while you're showing the cursor then this approach will work, and you can set/unset hit testability to control whether the cursor is displayed.